# What is the state of XMEGA programming from Linux?

Tags: atmel, avr, xmega

What are the hardware and software options for programming an XMEGA from Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find that command-line avr-gcc and avrdude work great on Mac OS X for programming xmega; Should work equally well under linux.

Comment: Which avrdude version with which programmer? My earlier attempts had numerous issues with PDI on the AVR ISPmk2

Answer (score 1):

Use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/R/eclipse-cpp-helios-linux-gtk.tar.gz) + [AVR-GCC plugin](http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/The_AVR_Eclipse_Plugin) + [AVR-GCC Toolchain](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/) and it should all work pretty great. [This link](http://paul.graysonfamily.org/thoughts/avrlinux/) has some advice on building and setting up the toolchain. You will (obviously) also need a programmer, and there are lots of options, but I use the AVR-ISP mkII. I will caveat this by admitting I've only developed for AVRs in windows, but using the same set of tools...

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm using avr-gcc v4.8.2 (both Atmel release and home-grown produce identical results), with AVR Dragon and avrdude 6.1-svn from September - there have been some updates since I believe.  avarice 2.13svn works, used with avr-gdb 7.6, which I believe is also a bit dated now.  Most of my interfacing in the meantime is via the Chip45 bootloader, in my case for Xmega128a4u